# Вывод значения из повторяющихся строк (select)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как написать select что бы он вытаскивал минимальный RANG из повторяющихся CALLS_ID, К примеру есть шесть повторяющихся CALLS_ID с id 9696318 Нужно вытащить 10тый такой же ид RANG которого равен 0 help

[image: TABLE]

Comment: *Как написать select что бы он вытаскивал минимальный RANG из повторяющихся CALLS_ID* `GROUP BY` + `MIN()`.

Comment: Можно в деталях пж )

Comment: Пожалуйста, откройте любой учебник по SQL и почитайте про группировку и агрегирование.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select calls_id, min(rang)
   from [table]
   group by calls_id
   having calls_id = [xxxxxxxx]
```